# When launching 'runas' can the 'Attempting to start (cmd)' be supressed, hidden, or otherwise squished?

Tags: cmd, hide, runas

Is it possible to use runas without displaying `'Attempting to ....'` and the command you're attempting to execute after providing credentials?

I needed to create a shortcut with an extremely long argument. 
So I found a way. It works as expected. However, When I invoke runas from the shortcut - and it reads the shortcut arguments, runas splashes all 1000+ characters on the screen in an ugly formatted stream of consciousness.

Can the `'Attempting to start (command)'` text that displays immediately after providing a credential to runas be sent to `$null`? Supressed - or hidden?

Comment: Have you tried [`> nul`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)`runas ...`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but, tried that and failed.  The windows shortcut separates the command from the arguments in separate properties making it impossible redirect to NUL.

Comment: even `> NUL 2>&1` ?

Comment: I was able to do this with  2>&1 ... however, that also gobbled up the PIV pin/password prompt.  The screen happily sits there waiting for the user to enter the requested auth .... without telling them it’s waiting.  I ended up working around that by adding Line like : read-host “Please enter your PIN number and wait” ...it works - but I’d rather just have a runas switch to suppress the verbosity.